# INTERPOLATION IN VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code for copy the column and paste it where user wants
the code is

```
 Set rng = Range("A1:EO1").Find(What:=COL, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
If rng Is Nothing Then
 MsgBox "Value not found in row 1", vbExclamation
 Else
  Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).copy
  ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(assume).Columns(c).Offset(, 4)
EndIf
```

Here "COL" is a variable that holds the value given by user and "c" is variable hold the string value to paste.

it is working correctly.
for example:- assume excel data like

0.25| 0.50| 0.75| 1.00| 1.25| 1.50| 1.75| 2.00|

the above line is first row if user enters the value say 1.75 then it will select entire column and paste it where user wants.

but When user enters 1.90 then it should interpolate the data between 1.75 and 2.00 and paste it where user wants

please help me

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How should it interpolate 1.90? And how should it know which column to place it in?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman for pasting the interpolated dat user will give the column name which will be holded by variable "c" 
and about interpolate if user gives 1.90 then it should interpolate the values between 1.75 and 2.00

PLEASE DO UNDERSTAND IT BCOZ ITS DIFFICULT IN COMMENT
example 
1strow:->1.75 |2.00
2ndrow:->10.9|14.7
3rdrow:->12.4|14.5
if user enters 1.90 then it should be like
1strow:->1.90
2ndrow:->interpolated data between 1.75 and 2.00 of second row

PLEASE DO UNDERSTAND IT BCOZ ITS DIFFICULT IN COMMENT

Comment: interpolation across the whole line? or just an average of the two points below and above?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Its Whole line

Comment: This takes your code to a whole new level....  it's very complicated to do this. YOu want to interpolate the data points between 1.75 an 2.00 for each row in the column?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman YES I want to interpolate the data points between 1.75 an 2.00 for each row in the column

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Please help with this!!

Comment: The only thing I think you can do is loop through all the numbers in the row and find the columns with the number right below and above the user-defined number. Than for each row in those columns take the average of the two columns. However, since that is the ugliest thing I've seen in a long time, maybe you want to rethink your process!!! What exactly do you need to accomplish, bigger picture?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  
dropbox.com/s/1r2ljp315pvbtyi/example.xlsx please go throw this one

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to interpolate between the two points where there's no exact match, the closest you could get is something like:

```
interpolated = y1 + ((xs-x1)/(x2-x1))*(y2-y1)
```

Where `x1`,`x2` are the values from your first row and `xs` is the "search" value entered by your user.  `y1`,`y2` are the corresponding two values on each of the rows below.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1r2ljp315pvbtyi/example.xlsx
@Tim Williams here is example of ma problem .
I used textbox and button 
please go throw this

Comment: Why don't you try it out first and post back with any problems you run into?